# How to create a table to see number of sickness calls and their begin and enddate with SQL

Tags: sql, window-functions

I'm trying to create a table to see all sickness calls ordered by `employeeID`, also showing the begin and end time of the period of 'sickness'.

```
SELECT
    EmployeeID,
    StartDateTime, EndDateTime,
    hourtype,
    LEAD(hourtype, 1, 'other') OVER (PARTITION BY EmployeeID ORDER BY StartDateTime) AS NextHourType
FROM
    dflxs.stg_registeredhours 
WHERE
    employeeID = 29
```

Screenshot of Query Result:

[image: Screenshot of Query Result]

Expected result :

| EmployeeID | Startdate | Enddate | Sickness call |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 29 | 2021-10-08 | 2021-10-8 | 1 |
| 29 | 2022-02-22 2022-02-22 | 2 |  |

Comment: Sample input???  Expected output???

Answer (score 0):

You are looking to display all sick calls sorted by EmployeeID and display the start and end times of the sick period. For this, you can use the time window (window function) and SQL analytical functions. Here is a sample query for this purpose in SQL language:

```
SELECT
    EmployeeID,
    MIN(StartDateTime) AS StartDate,
    MAX(EndDateTime) AS EndDate,
    COUNT(*) AS SicknessCall
FROM
    dflxs.stg_registeredhours
WHERE
    EmployeeID = 29
GROUP BY
    EmployeeID, hourtype, 
    DATEDIFF(day, '1970-01-01', StartDateTime)
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2
ORDER BY EmployeeID, StartDate;
```

This query displays all sick calls for employee number 29 in a group based on EmployeeID, hourtype, and the start date (StartDate) and end date (EndDate) of the sick period. It also calculates the total number of sick calls for each period and sorts the result by employee number and start date.

Comment: Thanks Mohammad, the query you provided gives me not the period of sickness. For Example first time sick from 2021-07-12 till  27-07-2021 (count 1) next period is from 2023-04-19 till 2023-04-19 (count 2) and so on...can you help me again?

Comment: You are welcome, We have used hourtype to select only sick hours to select sick periods.
`AND hourtype = 'sick'`
In the SELECT section, we have used SickCalls instead of dflxs.stg_registeredhours to select sick periods.

`FROM
    SickCalls`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    H.EmployeeID,
    H.StartDateTime,
    H.EndDateTime,
    Sum(CASE H.hourtype = 'work' and H.nexthourtype = 'sick' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS sickness
FROM
    dflxs.stg_registeredhours H
GROUP BY
    H.EmployeeID,sickness
```